# How to delete all the data under certain node of Apache IoTDB (normal command did not work)?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Please tell me how to delete all the data of a node in Apache IoTDB. For example I have three time series: `root.ln.wf01`, `root.ln.wf02`, `root.ln.wf03`, and I want to delete all the data of `root.ln.wf03`. I tried to use `delete from root.ln. wf03` command, and it did not work. Anyone know why this happened and how should I delete the data?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use any of tagged *things*. However, what does "it did not work" mean? What happened? Any error? If so, which one? That info might help someone else help you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the value of a certain time series in Apache IoTDB, you need to enter the full path of this time series. See if your full path of the time series is `root.ln.wf03` (seems like it's not). For example, if the full path of time series is `root.ln.wf03.user`, then you need to write the sql statement like `delete from root.ln.wf03.user`.